# Custom MatrialDatePicker dialog and TimePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker, material-components-android

in `MaterialDatePickerDialog` i want to hide edit button.
i try the following code

```
picker.setMenuVisibility(false);
picker.setHasOptionsMenu(false);
```

but it doesn't work.
and in TimePicker i want to hide edit time manual[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there isn't a method to hide the toggle in the header, but there is a workaround (it can stop to work in the future releases):

```
builder.setTheme(R.style.HideToggleMaterialCalendarTheme);
```

with:

```
 <style name="HideToggleMaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <!-- HeaderToggleButton -->
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderToggleButton">@style/HeaderToggleButton_Hide</item>
 </style>

  <style name="HeaderToggleButton_Hide" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderToggleButton">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
  </style>
```

[image]